# How do I resolve gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir ...node_modules when I am using sudo npm install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, digital-ocean

Before my last pull I was able to install npm packages with `sudo npm install`

The last package I installed was dotenv.  I can't imagine that would cause this problem but I can't say for sure.

but now I am getting the EACCES error even if I use root.

I removed the entire directory and cloned again with no luck.

server: digitaloceal Ubuntu 16.04

deployment method: Git

**ERROR MESSAGES**

```
USER@uhr:/var/www/mysite$ sudo npm install

> buffertools@2.1.6 install /var/www/mysite/node_modules/buffertools
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/mysite/node_modules/buffertools/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-139-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/mysite/node_modules/buffertools
gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> node-expat@2.3.17 install /var/www/mysite/node_modules/node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/mysite/node_modules/node-expat/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-139-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/mysite/node_modules/node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN mysite@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: buffertools@2.1.6 (node_modules/buffertools):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: buffertools@2.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.17 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.17 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/USER/.npm/_logs/2018-11-23T17_51_52_704Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "MYSITE",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",        
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "latest",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.7",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "rets-client": "^5.2.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "through2": "^3.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "MYREPO"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "MYREPO"
  },
  "homepage": "MYREPO"
}
```

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but don't use sudo. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451

Comment: It's exactly what I needed to hear... This fixed it.  Thank You.

Comment: Oh cool. Glad you got it sorted.